# Неожиданный результат работы с Nginx

Tags: linux, nginx, сервер

На сервер заведены два портала, которые делятся с помощью Host-name в пространстве Nginx. SSL организован при помощи certbot.

Наводился порядок с сертификатами и после того, как были удалены два сертификата (не связанные с работой порталов и давно истекшие) упал Nginx сервер. Самое интересное, что `systemctl status nginx.service` выдает

```
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2021-12-13 10:48:55 CET; 35min ago
       Docs: man:nginx(8)
```

Ошибка:

```
des. 13 10:48:55 u nginx[248435]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
des. 13 10:48:55 u nginx[248435]: nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
des. 13 10:48:55 u systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
des. 13 10:48:55 u systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
des. 13 10:48:55 u systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
```

Неожиданность заколючается в том, что оба портала остаются доступными (сразу оговорю, что данные не кэшированы). То есть извне все работает, как и должно.

Что я проверил:

1. `ps -e`, нашел pid  для `nginx` и вот, что там: три процесса и выглядят вот так

```
● snap.certbot.certbot.***********.scope
     Loaded: loaded (/run/systemd/transient/snap.certbot.certbot.***********.scope; transien>
  Transient: yes
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2021-12-13 09:39:30 CET; 1h 35min ago
```

2. Пробовал убить процессы связаные с `nginx`, но они поднимаются снова ( в `systemd/system/nginx.service` убрал автоматический reload и перезагрузил через daemon-reload, не помогло)
3. Пробовал убить процессы на 80 порту, но они поднимаются снова

Кто знает корень проблемы и куда копать, чтобы `nginx` работал "как надо"? Или может разъяснить, что я делаю не так

**UPD**

Добавлю проверку конфигурации `nginx`

```
~$ sudo nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

Проверка по портам показывает, что nginx их использует

```
~$ sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN
nginx     245336        www-data    6u  IPv4 3142018      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
nginx     245336        www-data    7u  IPv6 3142019      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
nginx     245336        www-data    8u  IPv6 3142020      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
nginx     245336        www-data    9u  IPv4 3142021      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
nginx     245337        www-data    6u  IPv4 3142018      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
nginx     245337        www-data    7u  IPv6 3142019      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
nginx     245337        www-data    8u  IPv6 3142020      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
nginx     245337        www-data    9u  IPv4 3142021      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
nginx     245338        www-data    6u  IPv4 3142018      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
nginx     245338        www-data    7u  IPv6 3142019      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
nginx     245338        www-data    8u  IPv6 3142020      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
nginx     245338        www-data    9u  IPv4 3142021      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
```

```
~$ sudo ps -ax | grep nginx
 245336 ?        S      0:00 nginx: worker process
 245337 ?        S      0:00 nginx: worker process
 245338 ?        S      0:00 nginx: worker process
 250704 pts/7    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto nginx
```

Comment: Запустите наблюдение за системным журналом `journalctl -f` и в этот момент попробуйте убить nginx — возможно, в журнале появится запись о том, кто и почему пытается их снова поднять

Comment: Возможно процессы зависшие и не реагируют на команду `kill`, попробуйте убить их с использованием сигнала `-9`

Comment: @ipatev_nn да именно так я убиваю процессы, без полумер) Больше беспокоит то, что все работает

Comment: @Dmitry, а если посмотреть установленные программы, нет задвоенного nginx? Может покажите дополнительно конфигурационные файлы nginx

Comment: @ipatev_nn нет, задвоенного nginx нет. В системет только один сервис `nginx.service`. Насчет конфигов nginxa: во-первых они массивные, во-вторых нет `default` и они полностью переписанные, ну а в-третьих они рабочие и протеситрованые. Ко мне тут догадка еще прилетела, почитать как рабоает плагин `--nginx` для certobt'a. Может он воду мутит?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Управление процессами nginx осуществляется не только systemd, но и скриптами init.d:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/nginx start
sudo /etc/init.d/nginx stop
sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart
```

Остановить процессы nginx можно

```
 kill $(ps aux | grep '[n]ginx' | awk '{print $2}')
```

или проще

```
 killall nginx
```

Если в логи что-то записалось, можно их отфильтровать:

- по заголовку команды процесса:

  ```
  journalctl -f _COMM=nginx
  ```
- по PID:

  ```
  journalctl _PID=1071
  ```
- по пользователю:

  ```
  journalctl _UID=1001
  ```

Вывести все PIDы и UIDы присутствующих в логах процессов можно соответсвенно

```
 journalctl -F _PID
 journalctl -F _UID
```

Answer (score 1):

Для проверки конфига поможет команда `nginx -t`, а для того чтобы перечитать конфиг `nginx -s reload`

Comment: с этим все ок, обновил вопрос

Comment: статус теперь в норме?

Comment: нет, все тоже самое. Я изначально проверял конфиг nginx'a, просто забыл в вопросе указать

Comment: проверьте какой сервис занимает порты 80 и 443 командой ```lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN```

Comment: вы будете удивлены как и я, потому как nginx занимает эти порты

Comment: иногда я встречал что сисадмины ставили поднятие сервиса на крон например как тут https://blog.xenot.ru/kak-nastroit-avtomaticheskij-perezapusk-nginx-apache-mysql-na-ubuntu-18-04-20-04-lts-v-sluchae-padeniya.fuck может у вас что-то подобное?

Comment: cron пустой, я его не трогал и никто не мог. Но я все же перепроверил. Я добавлю вопрос все процессы nginx как дополнение

Comment: в /var/log/messages нет никакой зацепки?

Comment: не используется этот путь для логов  `/var/log/messages`. Все разделено про процессам

Comment: поищите процессы, которые способны восстанавливать убитые процессы типа этих https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/336501/how-to-restart-a-process-automatically-when-it-killed-in-linux-centos

Answer (score 1):

Выглядит так, что все дело в сервисе certbot'а. Поищите его в `/etc/systemd/system/`, скорее всего там найдете определение, попробуйте остановить (дополнительно могут быть крон таймеры, проверьте `/etc/cron.d/`). Судя по информации [в документации](https://eff-certbot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/using.html#getting-certificates-and-choosing-plugins), для Nginx используется челлендж `http-01` который как раз занимает 80 порт.

Comment: я тоже так думаю, поскольку все сервисы работают и идут через snap.certbot. Проверю ваши предположения, дам знать чуть позже